# "No namespace declared for bin:bin" error with BaseX embedded in Java project

Tags: java, namespaces, xquery, basex

I have embedded BaseX in my java project with maven like shown here:

[Integrate BaseX with Maven](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Maven)

Im trying to run now a query via the [BaseX Query Processor](http://docs.basex.org/javadoc/org/basex/query/QueryProcessor.html)

If i run this query in the BaseX Standalone it executes normally.
If i try to run it in the embedded QueryProcessor it cannot find the
bin namespace.
A code example:

```
import org.basex.core.Context;
import org.basex.query.QueryException;
import org.basex.query.QueryProcessor;
import org.basex.query.value.Value;

public class BaseXTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String query = "bin:bin(\"0010\")";
        Context context = new Context();

        try {
            QueryProcessor proc = new QueryProcessor(query, context);

            // Execute the query
            Value result = proc.value();

            // Print result as string.
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (QueryException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The error it gives me looks like this:

> org.basex.query.QueryException: No namespace declared for "bin:bin".
>     at org.basex.query.util.Err.thrw(Err.java:991)

I am aware of the module() and namespace() functions of the Query Processor, but dont really know what to do with them.

Can anybody help me with using modules in the embedded BaseX QueryProcessor?

Comment: The binary module was not added but for BaseX 7.8 (which is not actually a recent version, but make sure you're having at least that one running). `db:system()` will return the BaseX version executed. XQuery also allows single quotes for strings, no need to escape double quotes!

Comment: Hello Jens Thank you for you answer! As you correctly said, my version was 7.6. I upgraded to 7.8 and it does work now! I cant mark your comment as an answer though

Comment: It was more a guess, I added it as an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [binary module was not added but for BaseX 7.8](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Binary_Module#Changelog) (which is not actually a recent version, but make sure you're having at least that one running). `db:system()` will return the BaseX version executed, so you can verify what version of BaseX you're running..